# ¿Cómo ejecutar el mensaje de else (false) y, no el true PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente condición para los roles de la página:

```
if ($rol_usuario === "administrador" OR $rol_usuario === "desarrollador") {
    echo "Super usuario";
} else {
  echo "Usuario normal";
}
```

En ciertas ocasiones quiero solo imprimir el mensaje `else` o lo que es lo mismo el `false` ya que no tengo nada que agregar para el `true`, para no dejarlo así:

```
if ($rol_usuario === "administrador" OR $rol_usuario === "desarrollador") {
} else {
  //echo "Usuario normal";
   header('location: index.php');
   exit;
}
```

Así por ejemplo redireccionar cuando intenten ingresar algunas funciones que no le corresponde, intente agregando esta expresión `!` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (!$rol_usuario === "administrador" OR !$rol_usuario === "desarrollador") {
    echo "Usuario normal"; //direccionar, no permitir abrir la página.
}
```

Pero no funciona, aquí en ejecución: https://ideone.com/ieU4FW ¿O de que forma debo emplearlo?

Comment: Toda esa condicion que pones deberia ser encerrado entre parentesis porque esto: `$rol_usuario === "administrador" OR !$rol_usuario === "desarrollador"` devuelve solo un true o false, por lo que simplemente haz esto: `if( !($rol_usuario === "administrador" OR !$rol_usuario === "desarrollador") )`

Comment: O simplemente cambiar `OR` por `AND`: `if(!$rol_usuario === "administrador" AND !$rol_usuario === "desarrollador")`

Comment: @Triby Hmmm pero que se supone que comprueba esa forma amigo, porque la del primer comentario al igual que la respuesta funciona https://ideone.com/3kTHxT en cambio probando su ejemplo no: https://ideone.com/qzYeW3

Comment: @Valentina, comprueba que el rol no es administrador y tampoco es desarrollador. Ciertamente, la mejor forma de comprobar es así: `if($rol_usuario !== "administrador" AND $rol_usuario !== "desarrollador")`

Comment: @Triby Si aquel ejemplo comprueba que el rol no es administrador entonces debió haber imprimido el mensaje, en todo caso ya solucione el problema, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miremos los casos...

```
IF (T or T)
    ejecuta aca
```

Ahora, vos decis que solo tenes else... con lo cual, para que se ejecute, deberia ser

```
IF (F or F)
    no ejecuta aca
else
    ejecuta aca
```

Entonces, lo que tenemos que lograr es que devuelva false...

Para eso, alcanza con darle vuelta a cuando devuelve T

```
IF (!(T))
    ejecuta aca como si fuera un else
```

Comment: es decir que no va así `if (!$rol_usuario}` sino así `if !($rol_usuario`

Comment: así no ejecuta :/ https://ideone.com/ieU4FW

Comment: @Valentina proba con if (!(condicion))

Comment: Ahora sí https://ideone.com/ieU4FW jamás imagen que tendría que ser así, genial algo nuevo que aprendí. Gracias